# How can I disable checkstyle warnings for missing final modifiers on lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, checkstyle

I am getting checkstyle warnings for missing final modifiers when writing lambdas in Java 8. I want the warnings when writing normal methods, but not in lambdas.

For example, summing a list of BigDecimals like this:

```
values.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b));
```

gives me the following checkstyle warnings:

```
- Variable 'a' should be declared final.
- Variable 'b' should be declared final.
```

Is there a way to make Checkstyle ignore this only when writing lambdas?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but you can get rid of the warning by using `values.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of checkstyle are you running. This should have been fixed in version 6.5, so if you are running an earlier version it's a known bug.

source: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/747

Comment: Ah, thanks. Updating to the newest version fixed the problem.